# How to use a field to update another field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, document

Here's an example of a document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("740b850f0406011059002b14"),
  product_id: 10,
  product_state: "available",
  old_state: null,
  ...
};
```

I'm trying to make an update where I store the value of the state in the field named 'old_state' and put the new value in the 'product_state' field.
I want to apply this operation on multiple documents.
So, how can I manage to make this operation?
The result should be like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("740b850f0406011059002b14"),
  product_id: 10,
  product_state: "outOfStock",
  old_state: "available",
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to reference the key name with `$` prefix to the new key you want to update with

> Note: This will work on MongoDB version >= 4.2

```
db.collection.update({
  product_id: 10,
}, [
{
  "$set": {
    "product_state": "outOfStock",
    "old_state": "$product_state"  // <-- Updates `old_state` key with the current value in `product_state` key
  }
}
])
```

> Notice the `$` prefix in `product_state` and the update block is enclosed in `[]`

This will update the current value of `product_state` key to `old_state` key

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RUQ1YHLjT0y)

Comment: I've tried this before, but the result is  not what I'm looking for, look what I get after the operation:  "old_state": "$product_state",
The value of  "product_state" isn't set, but the string is set instead.
plz check the exe in MongoDB playground.

Comment: i think its a typing mistake forgetting one [] check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sg59UD6c31d) its the above query with []. But this makes it a pipeline update MongoDB >=4.2.  We have 2 set operators, the update one takes only value so we cant use `$produce_state` , but the set aggregate operator takes expression so we can use the `$product_state`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the newer array form of `$update`:

```
c = db.foo.update({_id:0}, [ {$addFields: {product_state: "new", os: "$product_state"}} ]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that answers my question ^^.
Just one more question, the 'old_state' is a field that's already existing and declared in my Model, $addField doesn't affect that right?
Thanks

Comment: Correct.  In fact, you could use the `$set` operator instead of `$addFields`; I am just used to `$addFields` as a pipeline from "the old days."
Don't forget to click on the "accepted answer" button.   ;-)